# Logging across multiple modules with always changing filenames

Tags: python, logging

I have a logging function with hardcoded logfile name (LOG_FILE):

**setup_logger.py**

```
import logging
import sys

FORMATTER = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s")
LOG_FILE = "my_app.log"

def get_console_handler():
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    console_handler.setFormatter(FORMATTER)
    return console_handler

def get_file_handler():
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILE)
    file_handler.setFormatter(FORMATTER)
    return file_handler

def get_logger(logger_name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)

    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # better to have too much log than not enough

    logger.addHandler(get_console_handler())
    logger.addHandler(get_file_handler())

    # with this pattern, it's rarely necessary to propagate the error up to parent
    logger.propagate = False

    return logger
```

I use this in various modules this way:

**main.py**

```
from _Core import setup_logger as log

def main(incoming_feed_id: int, type: str) -> None:
    logger = log.get_logger(__name__)
    ...rest of my code
```

**database.py**

```
from _Core import setup_logger as log
logger = log.get_logger(__name__)

Class Database:
...rest of my code
```

**etl.py**

```
import _Core.database as db
from _Core import setup_logger as log
logger = log.get_logger(__name__)

Class ETL:
...rest of my code
```

What I want to achieve is to always change the logfile's path and name on each run based on arguments passed to the main() function in main.py.
Simplified example:
If main() receives the following arguments: incoming_feed_id = 1, type = simple_load, the logfile's name should be **1simple_load.log**.

I am not sure what is the best practice for this. What I came up with is probably the worst thing to do: Add a log_file parameter to the get_logger() function in setup_logger.py, so I can add a filename in main() in main.py. But in this case I would need to pass the parameters from main to the other modules as well, which I do not think I should do as for example the database class is not even used in main.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough about your application to be sure this'll work for you, but you can just configure the root logger in `main()` by calling `get_logger('', filename_based_on_cmdline_args)`, and stuff logged to the other loggers will be passed to the root logger's handlers for processing if the logger levels configured allow it. The way you're doing it now seems to open multiple handlers pointing to the same file, which seems sub-optimal. The other modules can just use `logging.getLogger(__name__)` rather than `log.get_logger(__name__)`.